# How to check (strpos(...)) all elements of an array efficiently?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I want to check all elements of an array and find out, whether at least one of them is prefixed by a given string:

```
public function validateStringByPrefix(string $string, $prefix)
{
    $valid = false;
    if (is_string($prefix)) {
        if (strpos($string, $prefix) === 0) {
            $valid = true;
        }
    } elseif (is_array($prefix)) {
        foreach ($prefix as $partPrefix) {
            if (strpos($string, $partPrefix) === 0) {
                $valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

**Is it possible / How to to achieve the same a more efficient way?**

(It's a cheap method, but it's called a lot of times in my application, so even a minimal improvement might appreciably increase the application's performance.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some sample data

Comment: Not a big improvement but instead of setting $valid to true and breaking out of loop, you could just return true there and instead of return $valid set return false

Comment: if it is truly at the start of then string then just use `substr($str, 0, $len) === $prefix`? Should be quicker if the strings are long compared with the prefix? As usual - benchmark it to confirm

Comment: I hope you've looked into using [multibyte safe PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try next solution:

```
public function validateStringByPrefix(string $string, $prefix)
{
    return (bool)array_filter((array)$prefix, function($prefix) use ($string) {
        return strpos($string, $prefix)===0;
    });
}
```

P.S. In case you have few large arrays (with prefixes), my solution is less efficient and you can combine our approaches like this:

```
public function validateStringByPrefix(string $string, $prefix)
{
    if($string=='') {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ((array)$prefix AS $subprefix) {
        if (strpos($string, $subprefix)===0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure this is more efficient: Here you will evaluate all values where the OP's solution returns as soon as a match is found.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to rome....

```
//your array to test for
$array=[];
//set valid to false
$valid=false;
//setup prefixes array or not
$prefix='whatever';
//make array if you dont have one
!is_array($prefix) AND $prefix=array($prefix);
//prepare for use as REGEX
$prefix=implode('|',$prefix);
//do the work
array_walk($array,function($val,$key) use(&$valid,$prefix){
       if (!$valid && preg_match("#^($prefix)#",$key)) {
            $valid = true;
       }
});
var_export($valid);
```

I used `preg_match` here, because `$prefix` can be an array, so the math would be: `n+ strpos() calls` vs. `one preg_match() call`

And after a single item matches, no more `preg_match` are called, just iteration to the end and out.

Comment: I don't know that a regex is going to be more efficient than `strpos`, and I don't believe walking the entire array is a good solution. At least the OP's initial idea returned early when it found it was valid. They are not trying to validate that *every* item is valid, just that a *single* item in the array is valid.

Comment: @haliphax as i say `there are many ways to rome` and for example have run test with 10000 iterations where 3 classes and 2 closure where created and strpos/implode/explode/preg_match functions are run in  each iteration. The script takes 1 sec. In this case here, there is no really more efficient ways, because the work is not so heavy. And in my example i check for `!$valid` to skip no more needed preg_match calls. Wahtever, i have just dropped the code here to give hints and directions.

Comment: @haliphax  And at last: if `$prefix` is an array with 10 prefixes the math is: `10 strpos vs 1 preg_match` What you say?

Comment: I say: your math is faulty. The first prefix would end the loop, so it's 1 `strpos` vs. 1 `preg_match` which is wrapped in 9 additional, needless calls to the `array_walk` anonymous function.

Comment: @haliphax `foreach ($prefix as $partPrefix) {`  have you missed the part from the original OP post ? `9 additional, needless calls ` can also ignored. But finally. There are many ways to rome and php isnt the best driver on the highway, so lets drive how we want ;) Have a nice

Comment: No, I didn't miss it - but I think you missed the `break;` statement which prematurely kills the loop. :P

Comment: @haliphax dont missed it, my point was lets say he has 10 entries $prefix and the 5th matches, then the math would be `5 strpos vs. 1 preg_match`. :) thing i now go visit the `Colosseum`. Enuff micro-optimization here......

Comment: @haliphax End finally just for the fun in it: My array_walk tests more `$string`s and the OB only check for one `$string`. So if `$array` has only one `$string` in it, my math will win ;-) But i also note that my answer is a little bit wrong.

Comment: My answer was pointing to this part of the OPs question `I want to check all elements of an array and find out, whether at least one of them is prefixed by a given string`. And thats sound like the other way around as that what the code of him shows.